# Permission denied when calling VBScript Scripting.FileSystemObject Folder.size

Tags: vbscript

I seem to have a peculiar issue when I call the folder.size of a folder that I have modify rights to. The files and folders with in the parent folder have inherit modify permissions. Yet when I call the size on the folder object I get a permission denied error.

```
Set mobjFileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objTargetFolder = mobjFileSystemObject.GetFolder("D:\data")

Wscript.Echo(objTargetFolder)  'Prints the folder path "D:\data"
Wscript.Echo("size: " & objTargetFolder.Size) 'Permission denied runtime error
```

Under special permissions, I have read access to the attributes and Read extend Attributes.

Note: I'm running the script on a Windows 2003 server.

Comment: Don't you have administrator access to directory "D:\Data"?

Comment: nope, just modify rights to the directory.

Comment: There is probably something within `d:\Data` you don't have rights to, so you hit a permissions issue while windows is looping through subfiles and folders adding everything up.

Comment: How is that possible? if I have modify rights to the parent folder, should not have the same rights to all the children?

Comment: Definitely not. At every child folder/file within the parent, these permissions can be overridden/changed

Comment: You can also get a "Permission Denied." if any file in the folder is "locked" or "in use" by another process

Comment: As @GWR said, your folders might in use by another process, check it using LockHunter or similar program. ;-|